# assign NSString

Tags: objective-c

I have an NSString called animation, which is called with the following (working) code:

```
 animation=[rowInDataBase objectAtIndex:2] ;
 NSLog(@"animation:%@",animation);
```

When I try to perform the following :

```
previousAnimation=animation;
```

The previousAnimation is assigned `ccsprite`.
When I try to logging `previousAnimation` to check its value with `NSLog(@"previous-animation:%@",previousAnimation);`, the application crashes unless `previousAnimation` is `NULL`

What am I doing wrong in my assignment ?

Comment: Are those two statements in the same method or different methods? When are they both executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to copy the string? If so you should be doing:

```
NSString* previousAnimation = [NSString stringWithString:animation]; // autoreleased
```

or

```
NSString* previousAnimation = [animation copy]; // retain count 1, need to release
```

otherwise you should retain

```
previousAnimation = [animation retain];
```

and release previousAnimation when you are done.

Comment: thanks a lot ,i did [animation copy]; , it worked , i was also trying stringWithString, but it crashes. can you explain to me why do i need to do the copy ? and whats the different from property ?

Comment: As the comments next to the lines of code say, stringWithString gives you an autoreleased object while copy gives you a retained object (with retainCount 1) which you need to release yourself. The reason it crashes with stringWithString is probably that it is being released while you are not expecting it to be.

Answer (score 3):

`animation` needs to be properly retained. You should create a property with a retain attribute for `animation` and `previousAnimation` and set them like this.

```
self.animation = [rowInDatabase objectAtIndex:2];
...
self.previousAnimation = self.animation;
```

Now both values will be properly retained between calls you will no longer have crashing issues. Just remember to release both values in `dealloc`.

Comment: thanks a lot. can you help me to shortly understand why do i have to do the property in that nsstring case ? i just couldnt understand that thing.  thanks a lot .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're assigning a variable that has already been released, so the memory's being reused by some other random object (in the case you mentioned, a ccsprite object perhaps). But it's hard to tell for sure without seeing the code in more context.